# How do I create a Trigger on a View that Updates a Column in a separate table?

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I am wondering if it's possible to create a trigger on a view after insert that updates a column in another table? Below is an example of what I wrote.

View Name: `VMC_FWD2`

Table Name: `TLORDER`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER QA_TRACE_NUM_INSERT_OI
AFTER INSERT ON VMC_FWD2
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
MODE DB2SQL 
BEGIN ATOMIC 
update tlorder set user4 = n.status where bill_number = n.number;
END
```

However this produces an error:

> [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0156N The name used for this operation is not a table. LINE NUMBER=2. SQLSTATE=42809"

and a little more research says you can't use standard triggers on views and that there is a workaround, just not what it is.

Comment: Hesitant to pull the trigger or are you getting an error or is it just not working?  Based on http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html I don't see why it wouldn't work, provided the user making the update to the view also has update privileges to `tlorder`.

Comment: So, is anything wrong with the example you wrote?

Comment: It says "-- [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0156N  The name used for this operation is not a table.  LINE NUMBER=2.  SQLSTATE=42809" and a little more research says you can't use standard triggers on Views and says there is a work around just not what it is.

Comment: Views support only `INSTEAD OF` triggers: `CREATE TRIGGER blah INSTEAD OF INSERT ON foo...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views support only `INSTEAD OF` triggers, so yours would look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER QA_TRACE_NUM_INSERT_OI
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON VMC_FWD2
...  -- skipped other declaration lines
BEGIN ATOMIC 
  update tlorder set user4 = n.status where bill_number = n.number;
END
```

Comment: Do I leave the ... in line 3?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. I inserted ellipsis in place of skipped valid lines, to show clearer what I've changed. Basically you only need to replace `AFTER` with `INSTEAD OF` in your trigger text, which otherwise looks OK.

Comment: I just ran this on our test server and it inserted perfectly now I am going to test it but everything seems perfect thank you so much!